# Running UrlFetchApp call repeatedly on error

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I use UrlFetchApp to update a webshop via Woocommerce API. It works like a charm, but some of the IPs what Google use to run UrlFetchApp calls banned by a security app on the server.

I am trying to rerun UrlFetchApp maximumthree times if the respons is not 200, by using a for loop. Unfortunatally it doesn't work. As I can see execution stop if error happen.

```
var url = "https://valami.hu/wp-json/wc/v3/products/...";
var options = {
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'method' : 'put',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'payload' : APIPayloadObject
  };

for(n = 0; n < 3; n++){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200){
      break;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve this repeted UrlFetchApp execution. Should I use try, catch blocs or something? Thank you,

Comment: `Unfortunatally it doesn't work. As I can see execution stop if error happen.` Quote the error. Explain *doesn't work* in detail.

Comment: I tested your code and is working fine, I try with 400, 403 and 404 error and it does make each request 3 times. What is probably happening is you're not receiving any response from the API, may be for a problem in your request or a timeout. Please post the error you're receiving.